# ACLs are not respected on FreeBSD

Tags: permissions, freebsd, acl, umask

I am trying to set default group permission for the folder on FreeBSD 13.0

```
$mkdir test
$setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rx,mask::rwx test
$getfacl -d test
# file: test
# owner: john
# group: wheel
user::rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
$cd test
$touch file

$ls -l file
-rw-r--r--+ 1 john  wheel     0B Jul  9 19:32 file

$getfacl file
# file: file
# owner: john
# group: wheel
user::rw-
group::rwx              # effective: r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

As you can see, the group permissions are not inherited properly. I do not care about the x flag for the user and group, that's a security mechanism. However, the group should have the write permission, which is not the case.
The same behavior  can be observed for folders created by the 'mkdir' command.

On ArchLinux the same set of commands works just fine.
On FreeBSD somehow umask takes over, which should be normally overridden by acls.
If I change umask to 002, I get the desired result.

On FreeBSD I am using UFS2 filesystem, on ArchLinux - ext4.

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Don't you think mentioning the file systems you are using might be a good idea? zfs, ufs2, ext4, btrfs, xfs, jfs, exfat, vfat, etc? Every file system has its own characteristics. BSDs aren't Linux, and one file system is not another file system, they are not the same. The fact you didn't consider this primary relevant information suggests to me the actual source of your issues. Note that 'Arch Linux' and 'FreeBSD' have nothing to do with this, it's just a matter of file systems and their features. ntfs features will not map to vfat or ext4 either.

Comment: @Lizardx While Linux currently doesn't have the notion of a native filesystem as it's distro dependent FreeBSD defaults to UFS.

Comment: Not in my last installs it didn't, it offered zfs OR ufs2, the installer was largely ambivalent about which I used.

Comment: Both ZFS and UFS perfectly support ACLs.

Comment: In my case it's UFS2

Comment: My point is the question was incorrectly worded, it should have been: I am failing to get features xyz on ufs2 running on freebsd 13 that I can get running on [whatever fs] on arch linux.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Google is working just fine. That thread explains how to enable acl on the filesystem. If I would have skipped that step 'setfacl' would throw an error, which is not the case, as you see in my question.

Comment: @Lizardx I have added that info to the question. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: While this particular difference isn't of any great interest to me, I would suggest when approaching gnu/linux vs FreeBSD/OpenBSD/Dragonfly differences, it's more effective to begin with: I am doing x in gnu/linux, how do I achieve similar  results in the BSD in question. BSDs likewise are not all the same, in particular OpenBSD and the rest differ significantly. Particularly at this level, you're dealing with kernel/file system differences primarily, but also the tools tend to be fairly different as well.

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Comment: Please try asking here instead: https://forums.freebsd.org/forums/general.3/

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see, the group permissions are not inherited properly.

As I can see, they most definitely *were* inherited properly.  You specified `group:rwx` and the output of `getfacl` has quite plainly told you that you *got* `group:rwx`.

> On FreeBSD somehow umask takes over, which should be normally overridden by acls.

Incorrect.  FreeBSD did the right thing.  `touch` created a file with `rw-rw-rw-` permissions, which your current `umask` setting (`022` presumably) modified to `rw-r--r--` in *exactly the way that it should*.

The first `rw-` became the `user` part of the ACE, the middle `r--` became the `mask` part of the ACE, and the last `r--` became the `other` part of the ACE, because *that's how TRUSIX access controls interoperate with things that set old-style permissions bits*.  User permissions is the owner user access control; other permissions is others access control; and [group permissions is the mask access control](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/unix-3-bit-acl-mask.html).

Your `touch` command, modified with the `umask`, instructed to make a file that only the owner user can write to, and everyone else (other user, owner group, other group, and world) can only read, and that's what the ACL that you got achieves.

If you'd added an inheritable ACE that said `u:nobody:rwx` you would have got an ACL that masked that to effectively `nobody:r--` in exactly the same way, because what you commanded was a file that only the owner user can write to.